# Как передать число с html в Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

есть верстка:

```
<div class="panel panel-body">
    <span id="all">140</span>
    <span id="pro">30</span>
</div>
```

Есть кусок функции JS:

```
 var dataset = [
        { name: 'New', count: 55 },
        { name: 'Pending', count: 43 }
    ];
```

Как заменить цифры с js на те что в верстке?

То есть должно получиться вот так:

```
 var dataset = [
        { name: 'New', count: 140 },
        { name: 'Pending', count: 30 }
    ];
```

Comment: дело не в том получается или нет. я даже не знаю как передать

Comment: `var all = document.getElementById('all').innerHTML` - вытянуть число 140, а дальше просто подставить в js.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Эх.. Нужно было бы на JQ, написал бы ответ.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, не считаешь странным, знать `jq` и не знать  `js` ??)))

Comment: @Air, считаю, но так получилось :)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, кстати не помешает ответ на `JQ`... Всегда найдется, кому будет надо...

Comment: @Air, ну так уж и быть, накатаю)

Comment: Если я ответил на ваш вопрос, то будьте добры, нажмите на галочку рядом с ответом и на треугольник вверх. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Для этого воспользуйтесь селектором [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), чтобы получить нужный элемент по его id и геттером содержимого элемента [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), чтобы затем вставить это содержимое в объекты.

```js
var dataset=[
  {name:'New',count:55},
  {name:'Pending',count:43}
]
console.log('Dataset was:',Object.assign(dataset))
let [all,pro]=['all','pro'].map(v=>Number(document.getElementById(v).innerHTML))
dataset[0].count=all
dataset[1].count=pro
console.log('Dataset became:',dataset)
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-body">
    <span id="all">140</span>
    <span id="pro">30</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

В вопросе нет тега **JQ**, но напишу, мало ли кому пригодиться.

```js
var dataset = [ // Есть массив
  {name: 'New', count: 55},
  {name: 'Pending', count: 43}
];

// Определяем новые значения count для массива dataset
var allCount = $('.panel #all').text();
var proCount = $('.panel #pro').text(); 
// Заменяем старый count на новые данные
dataset[0].count = parseFloat(allCount);
dataset[1].count = parseFloat(proCount);
// P.S. parseFloat, чтобы "число" было числом (а не строкой).
console.info(dataset);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel panel-body">
    <span id="all">140</span>
    <span id="pro">30</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Лови плюс....)))  Учи `JS`.......